Jolt specification, nested arrays are giving me trouble
I'm having trouble with Jolt transforms.
I have input json, but output is almost ok, I can't find where the issue is. Looks like problems are in nested arrays files.file and attributes.attribute[].@attributes.
Input json is converted from input XML using php.
This is my input json example:
{
  "ids": {
    "id": [
      "55551111",
      "55552222",
      "55553333"
    ]
  },
  "listings": {
    "listing": [
      {
        "id": "55551111",
        "id_type": "7",
        "category": {
          "hr": "Stan",
          "en": "Flat"
        },
        "date_posted": "2024-09-30",
        "date_updated": "2024-09-30",
        "name": {
          "hr": "Title in Croatian",
          "en": "Title in Englsih"
        },
        "html": {
          "hr": "Lorem ipsum html.",
          "en": "Lorem ipsum in english "
        },
        "transaction": "rent",
        "square_size_unit": "square_meters",
        "plot_square_size_unit": "square_meters",
        "currency": "EUR",
        "price": "1000.00",
        "id_code": "1234",
        "rooms": "3",
        "bedrooms": "2",
        "bathrooms": "2",
        "floors": "-2",
        "square_size": "78.00",
        "plot_square_size": "1300.00",
        "location": {
          "region": "Istria",
          "city": "Medulin",
          "town": "Medulin",
          "lat": "44.4444",
          "lng": "13.3333"
        },
        "attributes": {
          "attribute": [
            {
              "@attributes": {
                "name": "Water",
                "value": "1"
              }
            },
            {
              "@attributes": {
                "name": "AC",
                "value": "1"
              }
            },
            {
              "@attributes": {
                "name": "Power",
                "value": "1"
              }
            },
            {
              "@attributes": {
                "name": "Heat",
                "value": "AC, solar"
              }
            },
            {
              "@attributes": {
                "name": "Energy certificate",
                "value": "A"
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        "files": {
          "file": [
            "https://www.someagency.com/images//1727682341_ff670b3a-d2e0-43e4-a2ba-db01f3e2551c.jpeg",
            "https://www.someagency.com/images//1727682280_b77c1ac6-a7a4-4373-a583-5cb4f8ef237f.jpeg",
            "https://www.someagency.com/images//1727682273_96d73598-4ae8-4239-9fec-c95a88d947e6.jpeg",
            "https://www.someagency.com/images//1727682284_c0e8a299-72bc-43e1-b7f0-f12ad772bf15.jpeg",
            "https://www.someagency.com/images//1727682254_7cd13d3a-0983-488d-8a3e-6c2f9127b555.jpeg",
            "https://www.someagency.com/images//1727682257_27c7fb58-f36c-422a-a864-01f409d553d6.jpeg",
            "https://www.someagency.com/images//1727682275_164f351d-c0be-44ef-ae4a-3ae921d9ba8b.jpeg",
            "https://www.someagency.com/images//1727682339_fc78928e-7cc5-4d70-b649-9ed14bc48461.jpeg",
            "https://www.someagency.com/images//1727682250_2ee299a3-4f34-4e7c-b7fc-04e86847bed2.jpeg",
            "https://www.someagency.com/images//1727682267_74dc1290-97be-4f21-8a64-3634ac78cd2c.jpeg",
            "https://www.someagency.com/images//1727682263_47e27f27-2302-4041-b35e-2531bf1cad3e.jpeg",
            "https://www.someagency.com/images//1727682252_5d4e0c49-7602-4b7f-bb55-228ffa0ee967.jpeg",
            "https://www.someagency.com/images//1727682278_adf0a5d0-362e-4303-b74e-6477e7b715f8.jpeg",
            "https://www.someagency.com/images//1727682337_f255de80-c0f7-4350-a5bf-49ca7b72b79c.jpeg",
            "https://www.someagency.com/images//1727682248_1e04d842-a812-4734-89d1-d98f9c1e462a.jpeg",
            "https://www.someagency.com/images//1727682276_721a5ad8-54c1-49c8-8c2c-4a47f662226d.jpeg",
            "https://www.someagency.com/images//1727682282_b267ccc0-0e46-4749-8ecd-25608505d5d5.jpeg",
            "https://www.someagency.com/images//1727687021_18d7b894-d0e8-4756-b1d8-205e85bce793.jpeg",
            "https://www.someagency.com/images//1727687023_dc48defc-09fc-40ca-9f72-638dd3a71baf.jpeg",
            "https://www.someagency.com/images//1727687025_e71480fa-7133-4335-8b14-6051926c2cd3.jpeg"
          ]
        },
        "users": {
          "user": "241949151",
          "email": "testmessage@example.com"
        },
        "cname": {
          "hr": "Lorem Ipsum",
          "en": "Lorem Ipsum"
        },
        "text": {
          "hr": "Lorem Ipsum",
          "en": "Lorem Ipsum"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": "55552222",
        "id_type": "8",
        "category": {
          "hr": "Kuća",
          "en": "House"
        },
        "date_posted": "2024-09-30",
        "date_updated": "2024-09-30",
        "name": {
          "hr": "Title in Croatian for second entry",
          "en": "Title in Englsih for second entry"
        },
        "html": {
          "hr": "Lorem ipsum html for second entry.",
          "en": "Lorem ipsum in english  for second entry"
        },
        "transaction": "rent",
        "square_size_unit": "square_meters",
        "plot_square_size_unit": "square_meters",
        "currency": "EUR",
        "price": "12345.00",
        "id_code": "12512",
        "rooms": "3",
        "bedrooms": "2",
        "bathrooms": "2",
        "floors": "-2",
        "square_size": "78.00",
        "plot_square_size": "1300.00",
        "location": {
          "region": "Region",
          "city": "Medulin",
          "town": "Medulin",
          "lat": "44.444",
          "lng": "13.3333"
        },
        "attributes": {
          "attribute": [
            {
              "@attributes": {
                "name": "Water",
                "value": "1"
              }
            },
            {
              "@attributes": {
                "name": "AC",
                "value": "1"
              }
            },
            {
              "@attributes": {
                "name": "Power",
                "value": "1"
              }
            },
            {
              "@attributes": {
                "name": "Heat",
                "value": "AC, solar"
              }
            },
            {
              "@attributes": {
                "name": "Energy certificate",
                "value": "A"
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        "files": {
          "file": [
            "https://www.someagency.com/images//1727682341_ff670b3a-d2e0-43e4-a2ba-db01f3e2551c.jpeg",
            "https://www.someagency.com/images//1727682280_b77c1ac6-a7a4-4373-a583-5cb4f8ef237f.jpeg",
            "https://www.someagency.com/images//1727682273_96d73598-4ae8-4239-9fec-c95a88d947e6.jpeg",
            "https://www.someagency.com/images//1727682284_c0e8a299-72bc-43e1-b7f0-f12ad772bf15.jpeg",
            "https://www.someagency.com/images//1727682254_7cd13d3a-0983-488d-8a3e-6c2f9127b555.jpeg",
            "https://www.someagency.com/images//1727682257_27c7fb58-f36c-422a-a864-01f409d553d6.jpeg",
            "https://www.someagency.com/images//1727682275_164f351d-c0be-44ef-ae4a-3ae921d9ba8b.jpeg",
            "https://www.someagency.com/images//1727682339_fc78928e-7cc5-4d70-b649-9ed14bc48461.jpeg",
            "https://www.someagency.com/images//1727682250_2ee299a3-4f34-4e7c-b7fc-04e86847bed2.jpeg",
            "https://www.someagency.com/images//1727682267_74dc1290-97be-4f21-8a64-3634ac78cd2c.jpeg",
            "https://www.someagency.com/images//1727682263_47e27f27-2302-4041-b35e-2531bf1cad3e.jpeg",
            "https://www.someagency.com/images//1727682252_5d4e0c49-7602-4b7f-bb55-228ffa0ee967.jpeg",
            "https://www.someagency.com/images//1727682278_adf0a5d0-362e-4303-b74e-6477e7b715f8.jpeg",
            "https://www.someagency.com/images//1727682337_f255de80-c0f7-4350-a5bf-49ca7b72b79c.jpeg",
            "https://www.someagency.com/images//1727682248_1e04d842-a812-4734-89d1-d98f9c1e462a.jpeg",
            "https://www.someagency.com/images//1727682276_721a5ad8-54c1-49c8-8c2c-4a47f662226d.jpeg",
            "https://www.someagency.com/images//1727687122_dc48defc-09fc-40ca-9f72-638dd3a71baf.jpeg",
            "https://www.someagency.com/images//1727687120_18d7b894-d0e8-4756-b1d8-205e85bce793.jpeg",
            "https://www.someagency.com/images//1727687124_e71480fa-7133-4335-8b14-6051926c2cd3.jpeg",
            "https://www.someagency.com/images//1727682282_b267ccc0-0e46-4749-8ecd-25608505d5d5.jpeg"
          ]
        },
        "users": {
          "user": "1239194912",
          "email": "testmessage@example.com"
        },
        "cname": {
          "hr": "Lorem Ipsum",
          "en": "Lorem Ipsum"
        },
        "text": {
          "hr": "Lorem Ipsum",
          "en": "Lorem Ipsum"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": "55553333",
        "id_type": "7",
        "category": {
          "hr": "Stan",
          "en": "Flat"
        },
        "date_posted": "2024-09-28",
        "date_updated": "2024-09-30",
        "name": {
          "hr": "Entry #3",
          "en": "Entry #3 in English"
        },
        "html": {
          "hr": "Lorem ipsum description in croatian",
          "en": "translated to english html description"
        },
        "transaction": "sale",
        "square_size_unit": "square_meters",
        "plot_square_size_unit": "square_meters",
        "currency": "EUR",
        "price": "190000.00",
        "id_code": "159124",
        "rooms": "2",
        "bedrooms": "1",
        "bathrooms": "1",
        "toiletrooms": "1",
        "floors": "2",
        "square_size": "25.00",
        "plot_square_size": "0.00",
        "floor": "2",
        "location": {
          "region": "Somewhere",
          "city": "Over",
          "town": "Rainbow",
          "lat": "55.55555",
          "lng": "15.6666"
        },
        "attributes": {
          "attribute": [
            {
              "@attributes": {
                "name": "Elevator",
                "value": "1"
              }
            },
            {
              "@attributes": {
                "name": "AC",
                "value": "1"
              }
            },
            {
              "@attributes": {
                "name": "Power",
                "value": "1"
              }
            },
            {
              "@attributes": {
                "name": "Heat",
                "value": "AC, solar"
              }
            },
            {
              "@attributes": {
                "name": "Energy certificate",
                "value": "A"
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        "files": {
          "file": [
            "https://www.someagency.com/images//1727689376_img_7446.jpg",
            "https://www.someagency.com/images//1727528326_img_7448.jpg",
            "https://www.someagency.com/images//1727689380_img_7450.jpg",
            "https://www.someagency.com/images//1727528311_img_7437.jpg",
            "https://www.someagency.com/images//1727528315_img_7440.jpg",
            "https://www.someagency.com/images//1727528319_img_7442.jpg",
            "https://www.someagency.com/images//1727528364_img_7445.jpg",
            "https://www.someagency.com/images//1727529460_tlocrt.png",
            "https://www.someagency.com/images//1727529450_tlocrt.png",
            "https://www.someagency.com/images//Gabriela.png",
            "https://www.someagency.com/images//porec.jpg"
          ]
        },
        "users": {
          "user": "15124912941",
          "email": "someone@example.com"
        },
        "cname": {
          "hr": "Lorem Ipsum",
          "en": "Lorem Ipsum"
        },
        "text": {
          "hr": "Lorem Ipsum",
          "en": "Lorem Ipsum"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

:
and this is my Jolt spec:
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "listings": {
        "listing": {
          "*": {
            "id": "data.listing[&1].uuid",
            "transaction": "data.listing[&1].purpose",
            "price": "data.listing[&1].price.amount",
            "currency": "data.listing[&1].price.currency",
            "@name.hr": {
              "#hr-HR": "data.listing[&1].title[0].locale",
              "@": "data.listing[&1].title[0].text"
            },
            "@name.en": {
              "#en-GB": "data.listing[&1].title[1].locale",
              "@": "data.listing[&1].title[1].text"
            },
            "@name.de": {
              "#de-DE": "data.listing[&1].title[2].locale",
              "@": "data.listing[&1].title[2].text"
            },
            "@html.hr": {
              "#hr-HR": "data.listing[&1].description.data[0].locale",
              "@": "data.listing[&1].description.data[0].block[0]._html"
            },
            "@text.hr": {
              "@": "data.listing[&1].description.data[0].block[1]._text"
            },
            "@cname.hr": {
              "@": "data.listing[&1].description.data[0].block[2]._cname"
            },
            "@html.en": {
              "#en-GB": "data.listing[&1].description.data[1].locale",
              "@": "data.listing[&1].description.data[1].block[0]._html"
            },
            "@text.en": {
              "@": "data.listing[&1].description.data[1].block[1]._text"
            },
            "@cname.en": {
              "@": "data.listing[&1].description.data[1].block[2]._cname"
            },
            "@html.de": {
              "#de-DE": "data.listing[&1].description.data[2].locale",
              "@": "data.listing[&1].description.data[2].block[0]._html"
            },
            "@text.de": {
              "@": "data.listing[&1].description.data[2].block[1]._text"
            },
            "@cname.de": {
              "@": "data.listing[&1].description.data[2].block[2]._cname"
            },
            "@location": {
              "country": { "#HR": "data.listing[&1].location.country" },
              "region": "data.listing[&1].location.region",
              "city": "data.listing[&1].location.city",
              "town": "data.listing[&1].location.town",
              "address": "data.listing[&1].location.address",
              "lat": "data.listing[&1].location.lat",
              "lng": "data.listing[&1].location.lng",
              "zip_code": "data.listing[&1].location.zip_code"
            },
            "@category.hr": "data.listing[&1].spec.category_literal",
            "@users.email": "data.listing[&1].tenant.email",
            "@attributes": {
              "attribute": {
                "*": {
                  "@": "data.listing[&1].spec.attributes"
                }
              }
            },
            "@files.file": {
              "*": {
                "@": "data.listing[&1].files.src[@(1, index)]"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "listing": {
          "*": {
            "files": {
              "*": {
                "mimetype": "=split('\\.', @(1,src))"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "listing": {
          "*": {
            "files": {
              "*": {
                "mimetype": "=lastElement( @(1,mimetype))"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "listing": {
          "*": {
            "files": {
              "*": {
                "mimetype": "=concat('image/', @(1,mimetype))"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "listing": {
          "*": {
            "action": null,
            "listing_children": null,
            "business": null,
            "accounts": null,
            "files": {
              "*": {
                "role": null
              }
            },
            "spec": {
              "spec_id": 1,
              "attribute": null,
              "category_hash": null
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "listing": {
          "*": {
            "price": {
              "type": "=case(@(2,purpose), 'sale', 'total', 'rent', 'monthly')"
            },
            "location": {
              "country": "=case(@(2,country), 'hr', 'HR', '*', 'Other')"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]


Output looks like this:
{
  "data" : {
    "listing" : [ {
      "title" : [ {
        "locale" : "hr-HR",
        "text" : "Title in Croatian"
      }, {
        "locale" : "en-GB",
        "text" : "Title in Englsih"
      } ],
      "description" : {
        "data" : [ {
          "locale" : "hr-HR",
          "block" : [ {
            "_html" : "Lorem ipsum html."
          }, {
            "_text" : "Lorem Ipsum"
          }, {
            "_cname" : "Lorem Ipsum"
          } ]
        }, {
          "locale" : "en-GB",
          "block" : [ {
            "_html" : "Lorem ipsum in english "
          }, {
            "_text" : "Lorem Ipsum"
          }, {
            "_cname" : "Lorem Ipsum"
          } ]
        } ]
      },
      "location" : {
        "region" : "Istria",
        "city" : "Medulin",
        "town" : "Medulin",
        "lat" : "44.4444",
        "lng" : "13.3333"
      },
      "spec" : {
        "category_literal" : "Stan",
        "attributes" : [ {
          "@attributes" : {
            "name" : "Water",
            "value" : "1"
          }
        }, {
          "@attributes" : {
            "name" : "Water",
            "value" : "1"
          }
        }, {
          "@attributes" : {
            "name" : "Elevator",
            "value" : "1"
          }
        } ],
        "spec_id" : 1,
        "attribute" : null,
        "category_hash" : null
      },
      "tenant" : {
        "email" : "testmessage@example.com"
      },
      "uuid" : "55551111",
      "purpose" : "rent",
      "price" : {
        "amount" : "1000.00",
        "currency" : "EUR",
        "type" : "rent"
      },
      "action" : null,
      "listing_children" : null,
      "business" : null,
      "accounts" : null
    }, {
      "spec" : {
        "attributes" : [ {
          "@attributes" : {
            "name" : "AC",
            "value" : "1"
          }
        }, {
          "@attributes" : {
            "name" : "AC",
            "value" : "1"
          }
        }, {
          "@attributes" : {
            "name" : "AC",
            "value" : "1"
          }
        } ],
        "category_literal" : "Ku?a",
        "spec_id" : 1,
        "attribute" : null,
        "category_hash" : null
      },
      "title" : [ {
        "locale" : "hr-HR",
        "text" : "Title in Croatian for second entry"
      }, {
        "locale" : "en-GB",
        "text" : "Title in Englsih for second entry"
      } ],
      "description" : {
        "data" : [ {
          "locale" : "hr-HR",
          "block" : [ {
            "_html" : "Lorem ipsum html for second entry."
          }, {
            "_text" : "Lorem Ipsum"
          }, {
            "_cname" : "Lorem Ipsum"
          } ]
        }, {
          "locale" : "en-GB",
          "block" : [ {
            "_html" : "Lorem ipsum in english  for second entry"
          }, {
            "_text" : "Lorem Ipsum"
          }, {
            "_cname" : "Lorem Ipsum"
          } ]
        } ]
      },
      "location" : {
        "region" : "Region",
        "city" : "Medulin",
        "town" : "Medulin",
        "lat" : "44.444",
        "lng" : "13.3333"
      },
      "tenant" : {
        "email" : "testmessage@example.com"
      },
      "uuid" : "55552222",
      "purpose" : "rent",
      "price" : {
        "amount" : "12345.00",
        "currency" : "EUR",
        "type" : "rent"
      },
      "action" : null,
      "listing_children" : null,
      "business" : null,
      "accounts" : null
    }, {
      "spec" : {
        "attributes" : [ {
          "@attributes" : {
            "name" : "Power",
            "value" : "1"
          }
        }, {
          "@attributes" : {
            "name" : "Power",
            "value" : "1"
          }
        }, {
          "@attributes" : {
            "name" : "Power",
            "value" : "1"
          }
        } ],
        "category_literal" : "Stan",
        "spec_id" : 1,
        "attribute" : null,
        "category_hash" : null
      },
      "title" : [ {
        "locale" : "hr-HR",
        "text" : "Entry #3"
      }, {
        "locale" : "en-GB",
        "text" : "Entry #3 in English"
      } ],
      "description" : {
        "data" : [ {
          "locale" : "hr-HR",
          "block" : [ {
            "_html" : "Lorem ipsum description in croatian"
          }, {
            "_text" : "Lorem Ipsum"
          }, {
            "_cname" : "Lorem Ipsum"
          } ]
        }, {
          "locale" : "en-GB",
          "block" : [ {
            "_html" : "translated to english html description"
          }, {
            "_text" : "Lorem Ipsum"
          }, {
            "_cname" : "Lorem Ipsum"
          } ]
        } ]
      },
      "location" : {
        "region" : "Somewhere",
        "city" : "Over",
        "town" : "Rainbow",
        "lat" : "55.55555",
        "lng" : "15.6666"
      },
      "tenant" : {
        "email" : "someone@example.com"
      },
      "uuid" : "55553333",
      "purpose" : "sale",
      "price" : {
        "amount" : "190000.00",
        "currency" : "EUR",
        "type" : "sale"
      },
      "action" : null,
      "listing_children" : null,
      "business" : null,
      "accounts" : null
    }, {
      "spec" : {
        "attributes" : [ {
          "@attributes" : {
            "name" : "Heat",
            "value" : "AC, solar"
          }
        }, {
          "@attributes" : {
            "name" : "Heat",
            "value" : "AC, solar"
          }
        }, {
          "@attributes" : {
            "name" : "Heat",
            "value" : "AC, solar"
          }
        } ],
        "spec_id" : 1,
        "attribute" : null,
        "category_hash" : null
      },
      "action" : null,
      "listing_children" : null,
      "business" : null,
      "accounts" : null,
      "price" : { },
      "location" : { }
    }, {
      "spec" : {
        "attributes" : [ {
          "@attributes" : {
            "name" : "Energy certificate",
            "value" : "A"
          }
        }, {
          "@attributes" : {
            "name" : "Energy certificate",
            "value" : "A"
          }
        }, {
          "@attributes" : {
            "name" : "Energy certificate",
            "value" : "A"
          }
        } ],
        "spec_id" : 1,
        "attribute" : null,
        "category_hash" : null
      },
      "action" : null,
      "listing_children" : null,
      "business" : null,
      "accounts" : null,
      "price" : { },
      "location" : { }
    } ]
  }
}


Can someone help me with why I have six entries in output json, but three in input? I believe it's because attributes and files aren't mapped correctly so the problem seems to be that spec needs more work, but I'm new in Jolt and stuck here for some time and any help would be appreciated!
I tried different options regarding the issue and got either this output or none at all (no files or attributes in output json).
I'm testing everything in https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/.

I guess day after you get smarter.
Instead of this:
"@attributes": {
          "attribute": {
            "*": {
              "@": "data.listing[&1].spec.attributes"
            }
          }
        },
        "@files.file": {
          "*": {
            "@": "data.listing[&1].files.src[@(1, index)]"
          }
        }

it should be:
"@attributes": {
          "attribute": {
            "*": {
              "@": "data.listing[&2].spec.attributes[&1]"
            }
          }
        },
        "@files.file": {
          "*": {
            "@": "data.listing[&2].files[&1].src"
          }
        }

Hope it helps someone!
